# CSS Picture on small screen almost at top, and at big screen more in the middle

Tags: html, css

Basicly what i want is the picture " content " to move down to the center when the screen resolution goes up. Is this posible??

//html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>BBQ day</title>
<link href="CSS/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="powerd"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

//CSS

```
body{ background-color:#000;}

.container{ position:relative; width:100%; height:auto;}
.content{background-image:url('../images/BO_BBQdag-webt_03.jpg'); width:768px; height:607px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-top:0px 0.11111%}
.powerd{ background-image:url('../images/BO_BBQdag-webt_07.jpg'); background-repeat:no-repeat; position:absolute; height:72px; width:287px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;bottom:0px; left:50%; margin-left: -143.5px; }
```

Comment: Your `margin-top: 0px 0.11111%` is invalid. You can only have one number with a `margin-top`.

Comment: is this actually different screen resolutions or is this zooming in.  If zooming in then because of your margin-top being invalid in some browsers you will see the padding push elements down.

Comment: I ment the actual resolution. But I already found a solution :)
Thanks for the fast response!

Answer (score 0):

For that You need to get Screen Resolution when page load event.

```
 <script>
         function GetScreenHeight_Width()
            {
                        var h = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight;
                        var w = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth;
                         /** then you stored it into Hidden Control
                             As per resolution you can set position of the Content  with absolute or Fixed position.
                     You have to set position of the   <div class="content"></div>  element as per resolution..    
    When page load then call this function to set Actual height width of the Screens 
                         */                
              }
// Call function on page load.
GetScreenHeight_Width();
 </script>
```

let me know if not working.